# Why am I getting permission denied when copying from a directory I can read in Python?

Tags: python, shutil, network-share

I've got a very large Plex library of mixed file types on my home server (Ubuntu).  I'm attempting to pull the compatible types into a client iTunes library using python.  I've got it mounted in Windows 11 as `M:` using credentials that give me full permissions.  Here's the snippet I'm attempting to run:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import shutil


for f in Path("M:/Music").rglob("**/*"):
    if not str(f).endswith(".opus"):  # iTunes doesn't like OPUS files
        filename = os.path.split(f)[1]
        local_root = Path("C:/Users/username/Music/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes").as_posix()
        
        album_dir = Path(f).parent.as_posix()
        album_dir_name = os.path.split(album_dir)[1]
        artist_dir = Path(album_dir).parent.as_posix()
        artist_dir_name = os.path.split(artist_dir)[1]
        
        new_artist_dir = os.path.join(local_root, artist_dir_name)
        new_album_dir = os.path.join(new_artist_dir, album_dir_name)
        new_file = os.path.join(new_album_dir, filename)

        shutil.copy(f, new_file)
```

The `shutil.copy` call gives me:

```
PermissionError:  [Errono 13] Permission denied: 'M:\\Music\\Academy of St Martin in the Fields'  # the first artist path in the rglob
```

I'm able to traverse and list all files on the drive without issue.  In Windows I've got the drive mounted with full privileges, which I thought inherit to Python via the `os` module.  In my workplace, I am able to copy/move from the NAS to local drives without any extra logging in, also a hybrid Windows/Linux environment.

I have seen a couple cases where people resorted to using either `pywin32` or Windows own `net use` command via `subprocess` but with no thorough examples, and neither have worked for me.  How do I copy content from my mounted network share using Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens if you are trying to open a file, but your path is a folder.

This can happen easily by mistake.

To defend against that, use:

```
import os

path = r"my/path/to/file.txt"
assert os.path.isfile(path)
with open(path, "r") as f:
    pass
```

The assertion will fail if the path is actually of a folder.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up wrapping the assertion in a try/except.  I also had to add checks for the new directories, and switched the `shutil.copy` to `shutil.copyfile`.  It's chugging along now.